# Selenium Helper No Module

Tags: python, selenium, import

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "gen.py", line 9, in <module>
        from SeleniumHelper import SeleniumHelper
    ImportError: No module named 'SeleniumHelper'

# python accounts.py -i ../../data/twitter-creator.json -d regular -f 1
# python accounts.py -i ../../data/twitter-creator.json -d proxy -f 1

import sys
import time
import getopt
import simplejson
from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumHelper import seleniumHelper

class TwitterCreator(SeleniumHelper):

 MOBILE_URL_CREATE = 'https://mobile.twitter.com/signup?type=email'
 MOBILE_FIELD_SIGN_UP_NAME = '#oauth_signup_client_fullname'
 MOBILE_FIELD_SIGN_UP_EMAIL = '#oauth_signup_client_phone_number'
 MOBILE_FIELD_SIGN_UP_PASSWORD = '#password'
 MOBILE_FIELD_SIGN_UP_USERNAME = '#custom_name'
 MOBILE_BUTTON_SKIP_PHONE = '.signup-skip input'
 MOBILE_BUTTON_INTERESTS = 'input[data-testid="Button"]'

 DESKTOP_URL_CREATE = 'https://twitter.com/signup'
 DESKTOP_URL_SKIP = 'https://twitter.com/account/add_username'
 DESKTOP_URL_MAIN = 'https://twitter.com' 
    
import mechanize
import cookielib
import subprocess
```

dear python masters. I am getting selenium helper error. I posted the error above. I tried hard to decode the code. but I couldn't find where is the error. where is the problem? I will be very happy if you answer. good work.

note:there is also another file called selenium. I put the error code at the top.

note2: I installed selenium with pip. but he doesn't see.

Answer (score 0):

`from SeleniumHelper import SeleniumHelper`

--this is improper syntax. Ostensibly you could do `import SeleniumHelper as SeleniumHelper`? I'm not sure how this differs from simply `import SeleniumHelper` anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Source codes are here: https://github.com/S43ler/twag